# React, persisting redux state or reauthenticating via jwt to keep a user logged in?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux, jwt

I want to make sure this process is a good practice, and if not how can I improve it?  So the scenario I have is the user logs in to the website and on return of of a successful login response, I am storing the access token and refresh token in local storage client side.  Upon completion of storing the tokens, I think call an action creator to set me auth reducer to have isAuthenticated true.

Option 1, If the user closes the browser down and comes back while the access token has not expired, I would like to reauthenticate the user and automatically log that person in.

Option 2, I was thinking of was to use a package like redux-persist and would persist my auth redux state, but then if the tokens are invalid I would have to fail the authentication at some point and then set the reducer state back to not authenticated.

Would love to hear other peoples insight on how they are handling this scenario in a environment containing react, redux and jwt's.

So in my App.jsx I have something that looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        if (accessToken !== null) {
            //Here I would make some API call with either the access or refresh token
            //And if it's valid I would set the auth reducer to isAuthenticated.  Or I could
            //just check for the existance of the local storage item and set it the
            //reducer to isAuthenticated = true, do either of these make sense to do?
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <NavMenu>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={ Home }/>
                        <Route exact path='*' component={ NotFound } />
                    </Switch>
                </NavMenu>
            </Router>
        );
    }
```

Comment: @Shawan  token expiration part should handlled on server side and based in API response trigger non auth action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to check whether the token is valid instead of checking `if(token)//Logged in`. You can check if any API is called like getting user-profile-data  and if its returning with  `status:401` then you can call refresh token  and in some case it can happen that refresh token is invalid too. In that case you can just Signout the user.

If the API is returning the data then you can set the reducer state `isAuthenticated : true`. In your routes you can use `<Redirect to="/">` if `isAutheticated : false`

Answer (score 0):

here's what I do for my projects

1) created a helper.js file which has my helper methods which I include on all pages ( not the whole file but named exports) ( auth is my default export )

```
const auth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate: function() {
    if (cookie.load('token')) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true
    }
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  },

  signout: function() {
    cookie.remove('token', { path: '/' })
    this.isAuthenticated = false
    location.reload();
  },

}
```

then on an individual file I call this auth to check auth
 by using `auth.authenticate()`

I have a PrivateRoute which i use instead of normal routes for routes only accesible to Authenticated users by using below code

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props =>
        auth.authenticate()
        ? <Component {...props} /> 
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}/>
      }
    />
  );
```